# Can I copy the jdk installation folder

Tags: java, installation, java-5

I can't find a version of one jdk installer. Can I just copy the jdk installation  folder from another computer to mine without install it ?

Comment: What version are you looking for ?

Comment: you can search for portable versions(zip) on internet for the version you are looking for. It should be good.

Comment: @Chryor I am looking for this JDK 1.7.0.19

Comment: Short answer, yes. We provided embedded jvm's with out product by doing just this

Comment: @MadProgrammer you mean the copy is working well

Comment: Here it is : http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=java-1.7.0-openjdk

Comment: @Chryor And for windows ? I see like a Fedora as a distribution there is no zip

Comment: You're right, can't find it for windows. I'll keep looking

Comment: @Abderrahim Yep, it works fine for us, it means the users don't have to install the jvm's and it e can control when it gets updated (for our app)

Comment: @MadProgrammer thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

yes you can copy the installation directory, only change you need to do is to change you JAVA_HOME and PATH variable accordingly...

Comment: I just tried this for a `jdk1.8.0_40` and it didn't work. After installation it said that it could not find the `Object` class.

Answer (score 1):

Are you saying you can't find jdk 1.5, how about this: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase5-419410.html

You can also find all the old versions of Java here: 
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/archive-139210.html

Comment: And i edited with a link to the archive, with all the versions.

Comment: I am looking for JDK 1.7.0.19

Comment: Then find it in the archive link i posted (the second one). 
You cant expect everything to be hand-fed to you.

Comment: I did, but c'ant find it :(

Comment: Also, why do you need such a specific version. 
I think you'll do just fine with any 1.7 version.